# Git and Nexcess Hosting

Tags: magento-2.1.3, git

I am aware about using basic GIT and running basic commands but dont know how to start. Start meaning dont know how to integrate on local with online.

https://docs.nexcess.net/article/what-is-git.html

https://blog.nexcess.net/2011/09/11/source-control-with-git/#disqus_thread

I am using nexcess shared hosting for my project and read above articles too.

So what are initial steps to integrate?
Do my nexcess cpanel-user will be GIT-user for accessing ?

***EDIT:***

I have same concern like [this post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/15210) but could not get how to start?

Thanks for any help provided my any source.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, their regular hosting is pretty old school and not setup for version control.  Use FTP.  Most IDEs can sling to remote FTP connections with some customization.

Their homegrown cloud offering does support Git and such, but it's still very new and I've not used it.